# "how to fix " Error in in django " cannot import channals routing 'projectname.routing.channal_routing' no module name routing

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-channels

I am setting up a new server using WebSocket and I am facing some issues. Here I am using,

```
Python 2.7
Django 1.11
channel 1.1.8
asgirf 1.1.2
daphne 1.4.2
```

[image]

I am following this tutorial 
https://devarea.com/django-simple-channels-example/#.XOd9YHUzY5k

Comment: Did you install and import channels properly, your question says "channel"?

Comment: yes i installed channels